# How to select data using getdate() + time?

Tags: sql-server, getdate

I have this code:

```
select * 
from Table
where [Date] >= cast(getdate() - 1 as date) 
  and [Date] < cast(getdate() + 1 as date)
order by [Date] desc
```

and I need to change this part:

```
where [Date] >= cast(getdate() - 1 as date)
```

that the search start at 02:00 AM + getdate() - 1,

Something like this:

```
where [Date] >= getdate() - 1, 02:00:00
```

Comment: Is [date] a date or datetime data type?

Comment: the column -> [Date] is datetime type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server with the `datetime` type you can simply concatenate the time portion after first removing it. Try

```
where [Date] > DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(dd, 1, GetDate()), 0) + '02:00:00'
```

Comment: Is this comparing dates or strings with the `>` operator? Might need a separate cast to make predicate sargable. Edit: Nevermind, its the '02:00:00' that is implicitly convered to `DATETIME`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some basic time arithmetic for this: subtract 22 hours, after stripping off the time

```
WHERE [Date] >= DATEADD(hour, -22, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime))
```

You need to cast back to `datetime` otherwise you cannot add a time.

Answer (score 0):

```
where [Date] >=cast(concat(cast(DATEADD(day, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)) as varchar(50)),' 02:00:00') as datetime)
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working for me too, and this version of change have different way for use him in the other place